# Reset SQLite database by certain time

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there a way to reset (delete/create) a SQLite database/table on a certain time?
for example consider a table that track how much money you have spent on that day, then at midnight it reset to 0.
TIA

Comment: Why reset the database? You only need to save the time(if you want more certain results) and the date for each row, and when you retieve values you specify what results from-to you want to get. So you will get a result for a specific day or days or a specific time etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, you could [schedule an alarm](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

However, as long as your app isn't run, *nobody* will look at the table and be able to detect whether it's empty or not.
Therefore, the easiest way to handle this is to check the database when the app/activity is started, and if the last access is from a date older than today, delete everything.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to code like that. nice tip. I will return to you asap.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule you probably do not want to store calculated data in a database.  Store date/time and amount for each transaction and then calculate the total spent for whatever date/time range you would like.

Something like:

```
SELECT SUM(transactionamt)
FROM table
WHERE datetime >= 'startime'
AND datetime <= 'endtime';
```